# Вывод изображения на определённое место на экране

Tags: python, изображения, tkinter, pil

Я пишу небольшое приложение на Python и мне нужно вывести на определённое место на экране изображение, используя PIL и Tkinter. Я вывел изображение на экран, но оно выводится прямо на центр приложения.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def show_image(path):
    image_window = tk.Tk()
    img = Image.open(path)
    width = 500
    ratio = (width / float(img.size[0]))
    height = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(ratio)))
    imag = img.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imag)
    panel = tk.Label(image_window, image=image)
    panel.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="yes")
   image_window.mainloop()

show_image('e.jpg')
```

Comment: дополни описание своим кодом

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По всей видимости, вместо Pack нужно использовать другой менеджер компоновки виджетов (Grid или Place) - и скорее всего *Place*:

```
panel.place(x=75, y=20)
```

[Описание метода place](https://younglinux.info/tkinter/place)